# I have multiple ID's (up to 20) in a single row. Each ID points to every other ID in that row. I need 2 columns with all relations between all IDs

Tags: ms-access

I have been given an MS Access file that has a table with family relationships in it. Each row contains at least 2 IDs in it, but can have at most contains 20 IDs per row. It looks similar to this:

```
ID1|ID2|ID3|...|ID20
--------------------
101|105|107|...|210
102|104|   |...|
```

The ID's in each row are related to each ID in that row. So using my example above 101 is a relationship of 105,107,...,210. 105 is a relationship of 101,107,...,210.

What I need to do is make a three column table with two columns all IDs that are related to each other in each column. So the ideal result would be:

```
ID1|ID2|Relationship
---------------------
101|105|Family
101|107|Family
101|...|Family
101|210|Family
105|107|Family
105|...|Family
105|210|Family
107|...|Family
107|210|Family
210|...|Family
102|104|Family
```

I am unsure of how to do that without making a whole bunch of union statements one for each of the 20 columns. I am looking for other alternatives instead of making 400 union tables.

My Code so far but I really looking for alternate routes than this:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, "Family" as Relationship
FROM table1
WHERE ID1 is not null and ID2 is not null;

UNION

SELECT ID1, ID3, "Family" as Relationship
FROM table1
WHERE ID1 is not null and ID3 is not null;

UNION

SELECT ID1, ID4, "Family" as Relationship
FROM table1
WHERE ID1 is not null and ID4 is not null;
.
.
.
UNION

SELECT ID2, ID3, "Family" as Relationship
FROM table1
WHERE ID2 is not null and ID3 is not null;

UNION

SELECT ID2, ID4, "Family" as Relationship
FROM table1
WHERE ID2 is not null and ID4 is not null;

UNION

SELECT ID2, ID5, "Family" as Relationship
FROM table1
WHERE ID2 is not null and ID5 is not null;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Dont worry, it takes only 190 queries to compose the UNION. I think there will be no other choice. The data in your database should be stored in a table that looks like your query result. Maybe you can automate the process of writing that query.

Comment: Use VBA to write data to a table with that structure.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code for a VBA solution:

```
set rs = Open source recordset
set rd = Open writable destination recordset

While not rs.EOF
    If Not IsNull(rs("ID" & i)) Then
        for i = 1 to 19
            for j = (i + 1) to 20
                If Not IsNull(rs("ID" & j)) Then
                    rd.AddNew
                    rd.ID1 = rs("ID" & i)
                    rd.ID2 = rs("ID" & j)
                    rd.Update
                End If
            next j
        next i
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
End While
```

Even if the UNION were a good solution in this case, it would have been prudent to generate the UNION statement using code with similar loops rather than manually creating the text.  But from what I found online, there is a limit of around 50 SELECT statements, so you already would have had to create multiple statements to complete the task.  For that matter, rather than doing UNIONs which only select the data, you could have generated and executed multiple UPDATE statements instead.

Comment: Thank you for the pseudo code. Unfortunately VBA is not a strong point of mine so I'll have to see if I can figure out how to turn this pseudo code into something that will actually work.